# Should I get $200 for passing "Go" if I then get a card that says "don't collect $200"?

Tags: monopoly

Take this scenario: Someone rolled the dice and landed on Community Chest, passing "Go" in the process. They picked up the card and it read 'Go to jail. Don't collect $200'.

They argued that they should still receive $200 because they already passed "Go".

Comment: I believe the wording on the card is more precise. "Go directly to jail. Do not pass GO. Do not collect $200." This is talking specifically about the movement from the space where they are *now* to the "Jail" space. I.e. you do not move around the board to reach the Jail, you are transported directly to it. [Example card](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/monopoly/images/9/95/Chance_go_to_jail.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121122151318)

Comment: italian version of Monopoly does not have this issue "Go Immeditaly to the jail, you do not pass GO in doing this". That means that if you draw the card after passing GO, you take $200 because you already drawn the card.

Answer (score 77):

Yes, they would still gain $200 from passing GO *then* landing on a square that makes them draw a card like this.

You collect $200 immediately when you land on or pass GO, then the player would continue their move and land on Chance/Community Chest, then draw that card.

The text on the card specifies that you cannot collect $200 if you pass GO (again) in the process of moving around the board from a Chance/Community Chest square to the Jail square.

Comment: Hmm. Is a roll like this possible? Assuming you were on Boardwalk (as close to GO as you could possibly start your turn), you would need to roll an 18 to land on the first Community Chest that is beyond Jail.

Comment: @nasukkin: When you said that "you would need to roll an 18", did you typo that and actually mean 3? https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81oC5pYhh2L._SX425_.jpg

Comment: @Ellesedil No, because if you rolled a three and interpreted the subsequent Go-To-Jail movement as actually advancing across the board, you would reach Jail before you passed GO (again).

Comment: Ah, I see what you were trying to say now.

Comment: @nasukkin  but community chest is space 2 assuming GO is space 0 so yes the roll is possible.  I'm not sure where 18 is coming from.  Maybe the 2nd one?

Comment: @xQbert You would have to start on the Boardwalk side of the board, pass Go, *pass Jail*, and then land on the Chance / Community Chest in order for you to possibly pass Go a second time on your way to jail. So yes, the one immediately past Go doesn't work for this scenario.

Comment: @xQbert GalacticCowboy gets it :)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I see.  I thought we were talking about the $200 from passing go on the 1st pass which you obviously keep as the pay action occurs before you reach Community Chest.  I quite agree it would be impossible on community chest or chance to pass go twice on 1 roll (not turn)

Comment: @nasukkin You misunderstood the question. The question is asking whether you collect $200 for passing Go *before* drawing the card. Put another way, does the card's restriction from collecting $200 apply to the *whole turn* or *only the act of moving to Jail*? This answer firmly indicates the latter, as does the card itself.

Answer (score 21):

#### Yes, the player collects $200.

To understand this, let's step through each action the player takes.

- First, the player passes GO during normal movement of his/her token. The GO square reads:

  > Collect $200.00 salary as you pass GO

  Read plainly, this means the player collects the $200 the moment the player's token reaches GO while moving around the board. **See: [If you pass GO, do you collect 200 at the end of the turn or as you pass GO?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/if-you-pass-go-do-you-collect-200-at-the-end-of-the-turn-or-as-you-pass-go)**

  The [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) support this:

  > **"GO"…** Each time a player’s token lands on or passes over GO, whether by throwing the dice or drawing a card, the Banker pays him/her a $200 salary.
- The card subsequently drawn from Community Chest reads:

  > #### GO TO JAIL
  >
  > Go Directly to Jail
  >
  > DO NOT PASS GO
  >   DO NOT COLLECT $200

  [image: Community Chest "Go To Jail" card]

  The "do not pass GO, do not collect $200" is simply to distingish it from cards that state "Advance to <location>", which usually clarify that "if you pass GO, collect $200". In the case of the "Go to Jail" card, the player is sent straight to Jail without moving around the board (and potentially passing GO).
- The "collect $200" effect for passing GO has already resolved, and the text of the card only refers to the direct movement to Jail and not anything that happened before the card was drawn. As such, the player does not forfeit the $200 already collected.

Answer (score 9):

**Technically, the player should have collected $200 before even landing on Community Chest**. The text on the space says that you collect the money "*as* you pass Go", so the money goes to players passing Go as soon as they reach the space. If we really want to get pedantic, they shouldn't even continue moving (if the die roll indicates that they should move further) until they have the money.

**In practice, it's unlikely that anyone *actually* picks up the money at the moment they land on the space, but the fact that they *should* collect it then still matters**. They passed Go *before* the card came up, so they still get the money, because **at the time they should have gotten it, there was no reason for them not to get it**. The "Do not collect $200" on the card only matters if the character would pass Go *after* picking up the card, but *before* landing in Jail.